# Magento 2 Discount sales_quote_collect_totals_after

Tags: magento2.2.2

How to use this observer ?

```
sales_quote_collect_totals_after
```

to make a discount of $10 in the checkout page

[image]

Comment: this event will dispatch after calculating all the system totals as well as custom totals implemented. so, this event might not help you to make a discount of $10 on the checkout page. Can you please share the exact detail of your requirement?

Comment: I made a module which gets a credit balance from my custom table on behalf of customer id and shows the discount perfectly but I want to show discount  on checkbox checked on checkout page I am updating my question with a screenshot on my page then you will understand

Comment: You need to add flag field to quote table to use credit balance and based on that condition you need to apply discount. While checking checkbox from cart page you need to save that flag and unset that flag for the discount. This will work on weather to use store credit or not

Comment: can you please show any example because i am new on magento so i cannot understand most of the things you talked about